# Php, Mvc how to do a overlay?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm working in PHP, model view controller.

I run a action that is called `getallmypictures` where the result is shown on a view. When I click the result picture I run another action that get's all my related products to this picture, and that result it shown on another view file.

How can I get the second action result to be shown in a overlay on the same page as my pictures views?

This is my first action `getallmypictures()` when its execute:

```
public function GetAllPicturesAction(){
    //if (isset($_GET['showAll'])) {
        //if (isset($_SESSION['status']) == "customers_inloggad") {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fashionable", "root", "");
            $stm1 = $db->prepare("MYSQL");        

            if ($stm1->execute()) {

                $res = $stm1->fetchAll();


                require_once './views/pictureInspo.php';

            }
            else {

                header("location:../start/index?msgWrong=empty");

            }
        }
```

and the other action `getthispicture()` is required to this PHP file to show the result:

public function GetThisPictureAction(){

```
    if(isset($_GET['getPictureValue'])){

   // if (isset($_SESSION['status']) == "customers_inloggad") {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fashionable", "root","");
        $stm2 = $db->prepare("MYSQL");
        $stm=$db->prepare("MYSQL");
        $stm->bindParam(":picture_inspo_id", $_GET['getPictureValue']);
        $stm2->bindParam(":picture_inspo_id",$_GET['getPictureValue']);
        if ($stm2->execute()) {
            $result = $stm2->fetchAll();
            $stm->execute();

            $result1 = $stm->fetchAll();

            require_once './views/pictureInspo_overlay.php';

        }    }//}
        else {
            header("location:../start/index?msgWrong=empty");

        }

}
```

instead of showing to actions on 2 views I would like to have a second view like an overlay but still keep them in different actions.

The routing im using is /controller/action

Comment: What does your PHP code have to do with an overlay? And why tag this question as ASP.NET-MVC?

Comment: @Sverri, I fixed tagging.

Comment: you might have a lot more success in getting an answer if you tell us what mvc framework you are using. As it is right now, your question seems entirely without context and quite unanswerable.